# What is the time complexity of this agorithm (that solves leetcode question 650)?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, dynamic-programming, bottom-up

Hello I have been working on https://leetcode.com/problems/2-keys-keyboard/submissions/ and came upon this dynamic programming question.

You start with an 'A' on a blank page and you get a number `n` when you are done you should have `n` times 'A' on the page. The catch is you are allowed only 2 operations copy (and you can only copy the total amount of A's currently on the page) and paste --> find the minimum number of operations to get `n` 'A' on the page.

I wrote the following algorithm that solves the problem but I am having a tough time analyzing it's time complexity.

Here is the code:

```
    def minSteps(self, n: int) -> int:
        DP = [0] + [0] + [i for i in range(2, n+1)]

        for d in range(2, n+1):
            for i in range(d*2, n+1, d):
                DP[i] = min(DP[i], DP[d] + i//d )
        return DP[n]
```

So my intuition says this this algorithm is in between `O(n^2)` and `O(nlogn)` since in the second loop we are going "faster" than `O(n)` however since the step size `d` does not double between each iteration it is still `O(n)` somewhat for the second loop...

I am not sure how to analyze that one, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the outer loop - it is performed `O(N)` times.
Each inner loop is doing `O(N / d)` operations, since the jumps of the index is in `d`.
So the calculation is:

```
N / 1 + N / 2 + N / 3 + ... + 1
```

Notice that there are `N` items in this sum.

We can take the `N` out:

```
N * (1 / 1 + 1 / 2 + 1 / 3 + ... + 1 / N)
```

Which is approximately:

```
N * ln N
```

(The intuition is that by integrating the function `1 / N` you get `ln`)

So the complexity over all is `O(N log N)`

Comment: In case that very last step isn’t clear, look up “harmonic numbers.”

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is `O(nlogn)`.  Here is a more efficient solution:

```
 def minSteps(self, n: int) -> int:
        ans = 0
        d = 2
        while n >= d * d:
            while n % d == 0:
                ans += d
                n //= d
            d += 1
        if n != 1:
            ans += n
        return ans
```

This solution is based on the solution posted on LeetCode, but much faster.  The time complexity is `O(sqrt(p))`, where `p` is the largest prime factor of `n`.